# Is it possible to change the app launched by the Calculator button in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios

iOS 7 introduced the swipe-up Control Center which has a dedicated Calculator button (on iPhone, but not iPad). For those of us who consider the default four-function Calculator app inadequate, is there a way to make that button launch a different calculator app instead?

If applicable, jailbreak answers are valid but I'm looking for a non-jailbreak solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

These apps would then also accessible from the lock screen which would open a whole can of worms about security. Even the standard Apple apps do have problems with that sometimes, it would be even worse with 3rd party apps.

Answer (score 0):

No, iOS 7 does not allow you to change what each Control Center icon does. Plus, there are no jailbreaks yet for iOS 7, which means currently there is no way to do this. You can track the status of available jailbreaks at [jailbrea.kr](http://jailbrea.kr/), which is managed by the [iPhone Dev Team](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/).

Answer (score -2):

You can't change the button but... Open the calculator then turn your phone sideways to landscape view. Voila, scientific calculator!